# Django rest fraemwork, как в serializer добавить модель, связную обратной связью(reverse relationships)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте у меня такой вопрос, есть 2-е модели.

```py
    class AllProject(models.Model):
        # Preview
        title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок проекта', max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание проекта', blank=True)
        img = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Изображение', upload_to=path_image_preview)
        tags =  models.ManyToManyField(AllProjectTags, verbose_name='Тэг', help_text='Тэги используются для фильтрации')
        # Detail
        title_page = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок проекта', max_length=255, blank=True)
        description_page = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание проекта', blank=True)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Проект'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Остальные проекты'

        def get_path_name(self):
            return 'all-project'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

    class AllProjectImage(models.Model):
        fk = models.ForeignKey(AllProject, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_image_gallery,verbose_name='Изображения')

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Изображение'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Галерея'

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)
```

`AllProjectImage` используется для хранения картинок и он привязан к `AllProject` как я понимаю обратной связью.
В `admin.py` оно подключается так называемым инлайном.
А как такое же сделать с serializer?

```
class AllProjectImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AllProjectImage
        fields = '__all__'

class AllProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = AllProjectImageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = AllProject
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Пи таком serializers.py происходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вообще можно получить данные обратно связанной моделью?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти всё правильно, в `AllProjectSerializer` замените `image = AllProjectImageSerializer(many=True)` на `images = AllProjectImageSerializer(many=True)`
название должно совпадать с `related_name` для `AllProjectImage`.
Подробнее [тут](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)